# EHCache3 out of memory error on put

Tags: caching, ehcache

We want to use EHCache3 in our springboot microservice to cache binary objects (A PDF and some metadata) These objects are between 50K to about 12m. Using a simple test I can load the cache and see it working.

The problem occurs when a large PDF is cached. The following stacktrace is shown

```
2017-02-03 21:08:47.936  INFO 11 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] .e.c.i.r.LoggingRobustResilienceStrategy : Ehcache key 5dd12ae803ea06c4d37afe949090b934 recovered from

org.ehcache.core.spi.store.StoreAccessException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.ehcache.core.exceptions.StorePassThroughException.handleRuntimeException(StorePassThroughException.java:72)
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.AbstractOffHeapStore.computeWithRetry(AbstractOffHeapStore.java:1098)
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.AbstractOffHeapStore.put(AbstractOffHeapStore.java:306)
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.tiering.TieredStore.put(TieredStore.java:149)
    at org.ehcache.core.Ehcache.put(Ehcache.java:196)
    at com.pany.PdfGeneratorController.convertHtmlToPdf(PdfGeneratorController.java:79)
    at com.pany.microservice.pdfgenerator.endpoints.PdfGeneratorEndpoint.convertHtmlToPdfUsingPOST(PdfGeneratorEndpoint.java:23)
    at com.pany.microservice.pdfgenerator.api.PdfgeneratorcontrollerSpringEndpoint.convertHtmlToPdfUsingPOSTINNER(PdfgeneratorcontrollerSpringEndpoint.java:100)
    at com.pany.microservice.pdfgenerator.api.PdfgeneratorcontrollerSpringEndpoint.convertHtmlToPdfUsingPOSTPOST(PdfgeneratorcontrollerSpringEndpoint.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.encode(Unknown Source)
    at org.terracotta.offheapstore.storage.PortabilityBasedStorageEngine.writeMapping(PortabilityBasedStorageEngine.java:64)
    at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap.tryWriteEntry(OffHeapHashMap.java:703)
    at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap.writeEntry(OffHeapHashMap.java:687)
    at org.terracotta.offheapstore.OffHeapHashMap.computeWithMetadata(OffHeapHashMap.java:1947)
    at org.terracotta.offheapstore.AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap.computeWithMetadata(AbstractLockedOffHeapHashMap.java:582)
    at org.terracotta.offheapstore.concurrent.AbstractConcurrentOffHeapMap.computeWithMetadata(AbstractConcurrentOffHeapMap.java:733)
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.EhcachePersistentConcurrentOffHeapClockCache.compute(EhcachePersistentConcurrentOffHeapClockCache.java:158)
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.AbstractOffHeapStore.computeWithRetry(AbstractOffHeapStore.java:1083)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.disk.OffHeapDiskStore$1.invoke(OffHeapDiskStore.java:454)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I suspect that the problems lies in the configuration I am using for the caching but I can't figure it out. I am using constrained values in the heap and disk store to test proper eviction when the cache is full. Normally I would expect new content to push out older content from the cache, and give me lowered performance. But right now I am getting out of memory exceptions that I cannot explain. Is there something else to understand about the tiering of ehcache?

```
<config
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.1.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.1.xsd">

    <persistence directory="/root/cachexml"/>
    <heap-store>
        <max-object-size unit="MB">20</max-object-size>
    </heap-store>

    <cache alias="pdfCache" >
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>com.acquisio.microservice.pdfgenerator.msto.PDFTO</value-type>
        <expiry>
           <tti unit="hours">12</tti>
        </expiry>

         <resources>
             <heap unit="entries">4</heap>
             <disk persistent="true" unit="MB">64</disk>
        </resources>
    </cache>

</config>
```

Comment: Ehcache3's on-heap cache [doesn't properly support](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ehcache-users/8Mu4LkDOmnc/sYvvgn37CAAJ) entries with different sizes by instead under evicting. It doesn't sound like there are plans to fix it.

Comment: @BenManes this indeed looks like the issue I am seeing. Do you know of a way to work around this?

Comment: Ehcache2 was an excellent product for its time and, I think, still supported by the team. Since I work on an [alternative cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), my experience with Ehcache3 is too limited to offer advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace and inside the Ehcache 3 code - approximately as you do not give the exact version - it seems the OOME happens during serialization of the value so that it can be stored on disk.

When you put a value in a multi tier cache in Ehcache 3, the value is always written to the lowest tier - disk in your case. However in order to do that the key and value must be serialized. By default, Ehcache 3 relies on Java serialization to do that job, thus requiring keys and values to implement `Serializable` which, given your setup works, is the case for `PDFTO`.

In detail, the way this works is that the object is serialized and then put in a `ByteBuffer` which is then written to disk via offheap memory. But that means we need to be able to allocate a large enough `ByteBuffer` in order to proceed.

So the problem is not with the heap tier, since objects living there were already allocated before being passed inside the cache, but with the transfer to the disk tier.

I recommend looking into your overal heap usage and understand why you are so constrained or maybe check the serialized size of your objects. There might be a surprise lurking there if they have too many outgoing references.

Comment: I did reproduce your problem something really similar to your problem using a small heap. You indeed need a bit of room for buffers. Doing a memory dump should show a bunch of `HeapByteBuffer`s floating around.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting 4 entries onheap means that there can be 4 entries. Whatever the size. So if your heap is small and your objects large, you can indeed get and OOME.

Your solution is to give your heap store a maximum memory size (`<heap unit="MB">256</heap>`) instead of a number of entries.

That way, entries will be evicted when needed and before getting an OOME (assuming the maximum memory size is lower than what's left on your heap).

Comment: Hi,This is not what I am seeing, using for example 64 MB, will fill the space in the heap and then throw an out of memory exception. - Also do you know why having a max size of 4 entries would not evict the oldest item? My heap is set at 512m, it should fit without any issue.

Comment: That is interesting and would mean a memory leak. Which exact version of ehcache are you using? Eviction is "random" (a wise random based on sampling). Because keeping ordering on age is quite costly so that is a tradeoff here.

Comment: I've commented on @louis-jacomet 's answer. Since what I am explaining is not the cause, I pretty sure what he is saying is.